# VS Code added as favorite on the dock, but it opens under a duplicated icon

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-dock, desktop-icons, favorites

I have added VS Code as a favorite application on Dock. But every time I click on the Code icon, it opens under a new duplicated icon. Is there any way to fix? Below is my desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Visual Studio Code
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland --unity-launch %F
Icon=vscode
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Code
Categories=TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;application/x-code-workspace;
Actions=new-empty-window;
Keywords=vscode;
[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
Name=New Empty Window
Exec=/usr/share/code/code --enable-features=UseOzonePlatform --ozone-platform=wayland --new-window %F
Icon=vscode
```

I am sorry if it has been asked before but I was not able to find a solution.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.